# Using disabled attribute in input type checkbox

Tags: visualforce

As we have `disabled` attribute in  `<apex:inputCheckbox>` cant we use same field in input type checkbox as formula. I am trying to use as below but `disabled` attribute is not working  for me. Is there any syntax error or workaround. I need to use Input type checkbox only.

```
<apex:inputCheckbox id="{!dev.Deviation_Id__c}" styleclass="slds-input" 
        disabled="{!IF(dev.Priority__c == deviationLevel,'false','true')}"
     onchange="checkedDeviations('{!dev.Deviation_Id__c}')"/>

<input type='checkbox' id="{!dev.Deviation_Id__c}" class="slds-input"
onchange="checkedDeviations('{!dev.Deviation_Id__c}')" disabled="{!IF(dev.Priority__c == deviationLevel,'false','true')}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<apex:inputCheckbox id="{!dev.Deviation_Id__c}" styleclass="slds-input" 
        disabled="{!dev.Priority__c != deviationLevel}"
        onchange="checkedDeviations('{!dev.Deviation_Id__c}')"/>
```

The disabled and rendered attributes expect Boolean values, so this should do the trick.

Comment: First of all i want to use in Input type checkox and deviationLevel is value being passed from controller to Vf not string so i must use if i suppose

Comment: And in apex:inputCheckbox id="{!dev.Deviation_Id__c}" is not working since its not taking dynamic values.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal, we can not set dynamic **id** attribute. The **styleClass** can be dynamic. And the expression used in **disabled** attribute of  `apex:inputCheckbox` can also by used with Input type checkbox. This expression will evaluate itself as string comparison and return boolean value. You can try using an string property , I have updated the answer for this.